# Сравнение объектов DateTime

Tags: php, время, datetime, diff

Требуется узнать разницу в секундах между двумя объектами DateTime. Путем некоторого количества мытарств получилось следующее:

```
<?php
        session_start();

            $_SESSION['previousAccessTime'] = $_SESSION['currentAccessTime'];
            $_SESSION['currentAccessTime'] = new DateTime();

                echo $_SESSION['previousAccessTime']->format("h:i:s"), " - ", $_SESSION['currentAccessTime']->format("h:i:s"), "<br>";

            $interval = strtotime($_SESSION['currentAccessTime']->format("h:i:s")) - strtotime($_SESSION['previousAccessTime']->format("h:i:s"));
            echo $interval;
?>
```

Оно работает и в $interval помещается разница в секундах между двумя отметками... Но ощущение такое, что что-то я делаю не так. Возможно это ощущение связано с методом получения этой разницы, в котором я из объекта DateTime получаю строку, а потом превращаю ее во объект time. Насколько это решение проблемы кривое, просто не покидает меня ощущение, что я костыль сваял, а так поступать не хочется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `getTimestamp()`, чтобы сразу получить число секунд (с 1970 года).

```
$diff = $dateTimeLater->getTimestamp() - $dateTimeBefore->getTimestamp()
```

Comment: Меня не столько интересует вопрос "как можно", сколько "как НУЖНО". В этом вся проблема. А арифметическая операция над такими цифрами не повредит производительности?

Comment: @Devolutheist, ну, [вот что делает ваша версия с `format()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1d82eac13e8a35fa8b1660386e3c2d47519dff7a/ext/date/php_date.c#L1082) (и это без учёта конвертации назад в число), а вот что делает `getTimestamp()` — [раз](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6e806b45609b5659fd7459cdf18fa477d9dda3ac/ext/date/lib/tm2unixtime.c#L464) и [два](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/6e806b45609b5659fd7459cdf18fa477d9dda3ac/ext/date/lib/timelib.c#L201). Арифметическая операция тут особо ни на что не влияет (особенно по сравнению с пересборкой строк и последующим парсингом).

Comment: плюс в моем варианте обнаружилась досадная проблема с поеданием памяти, после 200 запросов прибавилось 20КБ.